# How to update SCNBox's material?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

I have a `SCNScene` with `SCNBox` nodes in a SwiftUI `UIViewRepresentable` struct. I save each box's material in a dictionary.

```
material.diffuse.contents = randomColor()
box.materials = [material]
savedMaterials[index] = material
```

Later, when the view needs to update, I use

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: SCNView, context: Context) {
    for (index, material) in savedMaterials {
        material.diffuse.contents = randomColor()
    }
}
```

The colors don't change. What else do I need to do to make the scene update?